# How to get only one alert per candle close in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Just like Pine Script indicators, which allows to choose one alert per bar close (in the alert notification dialogue box), Can anybody please elaborate what is the code to add the same in Pine Script Strategies? And where to add it?

Means I want that only one alert is created per bar close from my strategy.

My trade trigger codes are:

```
if longEntryCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if longExitCondition
    strategy.close('Long')

if shortEntryCondition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

if shortExitCondition
    strategy.close("Short")
```

From the pine script user manual what I learnt that I should modify my commands as follows:

```
if longEntryCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long ,  alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if shortEntryCondition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short , alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Is it Okay? PLEASE HELP!